# Wire to board connections; turret terminals

Tags: pcb, connector

Are turret terminals robust for wire to boards connections as shown below? Are there other/better ways to implement this? It might depend on the application I think. I've seen these types of connections used for transmitting power instead of signals.

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem with using a screw/cage clamp terminal? You need to define what you need to be "robust"... Does the wire get pulled on? Does the wire move a lot?

Comment: Yes, the wire is in harsh environments. It moves sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is a bad idea. Two problems come to mind immediately. One of the first things I was taught about soldered connections is that you should not rely on the strength of the solder to hold it together, that connection is doing that. In addition soldering the wire creates a stiff area which can result in fatigue failures of the wire depending on the operating environment.

I much prefer to use screw down or lever locked pcb wire connectors like the following.

[image: Image from TE Connectivity]
Image TE Connectivity

[image: Image from Phoenix contact] 
Image Phoenix contact

Depending on your needs in a production environment you might want to consider a combination of cable connector and a compatible PCB header.

Comment: I would like a connector to connect a three phase power supply to a low power circuit.

Comment: That can not be answered as is. First that makes your question a shopping question which is off topic here. You need to specify the voltage and current that the connector needs to carry. Then you need to decide the trade-off between labour costs and parts cost for the many different connector solutions that are available. That will depend on your application and production volume.

Comment: Also note that wires inserted into a terminal block should be bare copper and *not* tinned for the same reasons.

Comment: Can you please provide a citation for the graphics you copied into your answer? We want to make sure that we give credit to the original creator/owner of the images.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Done, however I was considering removing the in image citation on the second image to avoid coming over as recommending one particular manufacturer, where is the balance?

Comment: I understand your concern. I think you handled it well...you didn't appear to be actually recommending any particular manufacturer's product.